# Content not being returned in console

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So I just upgraded to Xcode 7, which has Swift 2. When I run `print("Test")`, I don't get anything in my console other than

```
CoreFoundation = 1142.130000
CoreFoundation = 1142.130000
```

This is what a "running" project looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCwnE.png

Additionally the app opens, and closes instantly upon running, with no errors returned. Any ideas?

Comment: "cause CoreFoundation is not enabled on the current project" Sure is it. You import UIKit, it imports Core Foundation.

Comment: My bad, meant to say CoreData. @matt

Comment: Why would you mean to say that? Core Data is not mentioned in the console.

Comment: Because I got Core Data and Core Foundation mixed up since upon creating the project there's an open for Core Data, that's what I thought Core Foundation was :) @matt

Comment: Also, the screen shot you linked to does _not_ show the project "running". It is stopped.

Comment: Plus, perhaps you are having problems trying to run on the device, which is what you are apparently trying to do, to judge by your screen shot. Try running on a simulator instead (yes, you're getting opposite advice here, I know).

Comment: No change whatsoever, same results. Anymore suggestions? I find it strange that I don't get any errors either since the app crashes frequently @matt

Comment: I'd say delete Xcode and install it again. I'm using Xcode beta 7 and Swift 2 constantly and it works great for me.

Answer (score -1):

This is a known bug with the iOS 9 simulator. (Mentioned in the beta release notes). Try running this code on your device.

Comment: What precisely do the beta release notes say about this?

Comment: @matt "Printing from Simulator does not work with the iOS 9.0 beta runtime. (19754468)
Workaround: Test printing from a device with iOS 9.0 beta."

Comment: That prefers to printing to a printer - not logging to the Console. Logging to the Console works perfectly well.